# More general reflection formula for Gamma function

Tags: special-functions, functional-equations, gamma-function

It is know that $\Gamma(z)\,  \Gamma{(1-z)}=\pi \csc( \pi z)$.   Is there any formula for $\Gamma{(a+z)}\Gamma{(a-z)}$ where $a$ is a rational number, i. e., $a=p/k$  with $p, k$ integers and  $z$ is a complex number ?

Comment: But it does not look to me as a generalization because there is no $a$ that you can plug into $\Gamma{(a+z)}\Gamma{(a-z)}$ to get $\Gamma(z)\,  \Gamma{(1-z)}$?

Comment: But try to explore what you have here : [Gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) as a starting point.

Comment: For a=0 or a=1 the expression $\Gamma{(a+z)} \Gamma{(a-z)} $ can be expressed in terms of the reflection formula above. But what about $a \neq 0$ or $a\neq 1$ ?

Answer (score 4):

For $a\in\mathbb Z>0$ we have $\Gamma(a+z)\Gamma(a-z)=-\dfrac{\pi}{z\sin(\pi z)}~\cdot~\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^{a-1}(k^2-z^2)$.

For $a\in\mathbb Z<0$ we have $\Gamma(a+z)\Gamma(a-z)=-\dfrac{\pi}{z\sin(\pi z)}\bigg/\,\displaystyle\prod_{k=a}^{-1}(k^2-z^2).$

This is obvious from the fundamental property of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), $\Gamma(z+1)=z\,\Gamma(z)$, combined with the afore-mentioned [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula). But for $a\in\mathbb Q\setminus\mathbb Z$ no such general formula is known, except for $a=k+\dfrac12$ , in which case we use the [fact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem#Gamma_function-Legendre_function) that $\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac12+z\bigg)\Gamma\bigg(\dfrac12-z\bigg)=$ $=\dfrac\pi{\cos\pi z}$ as a starting point, to arrive at two other formulas, very similar to the ones presented above.

Comment: We also have $\dfrac{\Gamma\Big(\tfrac14+x\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(\tfrac14-x\Big)} ~=~ \pi^{2x}\cdot\dfrac{\zeta\Big(\tfrac12-2x\Big)}{\zeta\Big(\tfrac12+2x\Big)}.$